# Obtaining the size of the neighborhood in ISOMAP algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, size

I am studying the original article of ISOMAP algorithm and I can't understand how to obtain empirically the proper size of the neighborhood (epsilon).

It says that it can be obtained with a trade-off between "the fraction of the variance in geodesic distance estimates not accounted for in the Euclidean" and the number of nearest points.

But as a matter of fact, I do not have the real geodesic distances in the manifold, right? So, how can I calculate the residual variance between the real distances and their euclidean estimates?

Thanks in advance to everyone who will want to help.

Best regards,

Valentina

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  Everyone uses a neighborhood size of 8-12.

Longer Answer:  You probably *can't* measure the difference between Euclidean distance and the manifold distance.  Isomap approximates the geodesic distance -- using the shortest path distance on the nearby-neighbors graph.

How good is that approximation?
IF you have tons and tons of points, so that you can, for example pick a neighborhood size of 100, and all 100 points are nearby your point, and the path to all 100 points lies very close to the manifold, then you could use a neighborhood size of 100 and the shortest path graph would probably be a very close approximation to the geodesic distances.

Usually, you don't have so many points.  So then you are stuck with a trade-off:

use too few points, and your shortest path has to zig-zag a little

use too many points and there may be a link the directly connects points that should be far away (on the manifold), but was included in your neighborhood.

How do you solve this tradeoff?

Well, choose 8-12 points.  IF you manifold is 2-3 dimensional (it may live in a high dimensional space, but the points on the manifold only vary in a few dimensions near each point), then 8-12 points gives some options for each point to link in a bunch of different directions.

If your manifold is more than 2-3 dimensional, then Isomap probably won't work, you would need to have a neighborhood size that is larger (more points!) so that you have reasonable options to estimate your geodesic path with links to nearby neighbors.

Interesting side note: IF you choose your neighborhood size to be all the points, Isomap == PCA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have understood it is essential to choose the size of the neighborhood just right; I will try with 8-12 neighbors like you suggest. Thank you :)